# Encoding TargetDataLine data into Ogg Vorbis file

Tags: java, encoding, javasound

Sorry if this seems like a straightforward question but it's my very first time experimenting with sound in programming.

What I'm trying to achieve here is to encode the data obtained through a TargetDataLine object into a .ogg file. My starting point was the official Java Documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html.

I'm using JavaZoom's Vorbis API http://www.javazoom.net/vorbisspi/vorbisspi.html.

```
private static void recordAudio(int id) {

    Map<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    myMap.put("duration", 0);
    myMap.put("title", "title_test");
    myMap.put("author", "author_test");
    myMap.put("album", "album_test");
    myMap.put("date", "date_test");
    myMap.put("copyright", "copyright_test");
    myMap.put("comment", "comment_test");

    VorbisAudioFormat format = new VorbisAudioFormat(VorbisEncoding.VORBISENC, 48000.F, 16, 2, 4, 48000.F, true, myMap);
    Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()[id]);

    TargetDataLine line;
    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
    if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
        System.out.println("Line is not supported.");
    }
    try {
        line = (TargetDataLine) mixer.getLine(info);
        line.open(format);
        line.start();

        AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(line);
        File auFile = new File("path/stream_test.ogg");
        AudioFileFormat.Type fileType = VorbisFileFormatType.OGG;
        AudioSystem.write(ais, fileType, auFile);

    } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
        System.out.println("Line is unavailable.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

With this code I'm getting the following output in console.

```
Line is not supported.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Line unsupported: interface TargetDataLine supporting format VORBISENC 48000.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, 
    at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice.getLine(Unknown Source)
    at test_mixer.Main.recordAudio(Main.java:60)
    at test_mixer.Main.main(Main.java:35)
```

I've tried changing the enconding to `VorbisEncoding.PCM_SIGNED` but then the console throws the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: could not write audio file: file type not supported: OGG
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.write(Unknown Source)
at test_mixer.Main.recordAudio(Main.java:66)
at test_mixer.Main.main(Main.java:35)
```

Comment: have  a look at AudioSystem.html; then have a look at AudioFileFormat.Type.html; do you see vorbis as supported anywhere??

Comment: @gpasch The OP is trying to use the Vorbis SPI code which adds support for Vorbis to Java Sound.

Comment: Is alternate path possible for you: e.g., write to wav, then use something like audacity.com to convert from wav to ogg? If so, I'm sure we can help with writing to wav part. IDK if there is a library for writing to ogg directly, available. Possibly there is in LWJGL 3, which uses an OpenAL library that I know reads ogg, and likely writes it as well.

Comment: Hey @PhilFreihofner , that path you're proposing isn't possible for me as all the data is going to be streamed to Icecast and should be converted to ogg in real time prior to send it into the server, so I need a format that doesn't need a specific length. Thanks for proposing an alternate path!

Comment: The OpenAL Soft approach doesn't look very promising either. But maybe this project can help you: https://github.com/Gagravarr/VorbisJava "Currently, support for the Ogg container is fairly complete, offering
the ability to read, write, add and change streams within an Ogg file."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Vorbis SPI code you are using is based on the JOrbis Ogg **decoder**.

It only supports reading Ogg files, it does not support encoding and writing Ogg files.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying! Would writing and rewriting a fixed size .au file (for example) and then use Xuggler or a Java wrapper around ffmpeg to get the encoding right work?

Comment: I would think that would be OK.